# I want to combine the 4 soql from 4 diff objects and need to download as a JSON. how to achieve this, my queries as follows

Tags: soql, json

list aa =  new list();
list aa =  new list();
list aa =  new list();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Map<String, Object> m = new Map<String, Object>{
        'obj' => objmapp,
        'fld' => fldmapp,
        'filter' => filtermapp,
        'code' => codemapp
        };

String s = JSON.serializePretty(m);
```

Take a look at the [JSON Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_System_Json.htm) documentation.

Comment: In Map The double Quotes are not allowing.

Comment: @ArjunReddy Getting my JavaScript and Apex mixed up. See the change from `:` to `=>` in the answer.

Comment: I am getting the below errors: 1. Unrecognized symbol '"', which is not a valid Apex identifier.  2.Variable does not exist: obj

Comment: @ArjunReddy My bad. Single quotes needed in Apex - I've edited the answer again.

Comment: Thank you very much for u r effort. Its working really grate. Thank you so much.

Comment: How to deserialize that converted string. i tried with This "   map<string, sObject> maap=new Map<string, sObject>();
   maap= (map<string, sObject>)JSON.deserialize(con, map<string, sObject>.class);" , But i am getting following exception: "Json Deserialization failed on token 'obj' and has left off in the middle of parsing a row. Will go to end of row to begin parsing the next row". Plz help.

Comment: @ArjunReddy Using `Map<String, List<SObject>>` should work.

Comment: I want to insert that string, here is the relation, objmap is the parent for both fldmapp and filtermapp,  And codemapp is the child of fldmapp. can you guide me how to achieve this?

Comment: @ArjunReddy Time to stop here. If you have another question please ask it as a new question with all the background details.